# Calculated Constants in C#

Tags: c#, operators, jit, cil

Good morning, afternoon or night,

Will either the MSIL or the JIT compiler replace things like `1 << 5` or `1 << 31` in the code with `32` and `2147483648`, respectively, or will they wait for method execution to evaluate those constants "just in time" since they involve other methods (operators)?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It depends on the context but most of the time they will be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: these are comile time constants -> are evaluated at comile time

Answer (score 6):

Try it.

The following code

```
    static void Main ( string[] args )
    {
        Console.WriteLine ( 1 << 4 );
    }
```

Gets compiled to

```
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.s   16
  IL_0003:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
  IL_0008:  nop
  IL_0009:  ret
```

It just loads the constant 16 and passes it to WriteLine.

Comment: Constants are immutable values which are known at compile time and do not change for the life of the program http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173119(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Look at the compiled IL for a program that just does `Console.WriteLine(1 << 5)` and you'll see it's the same as that for `Console.WriteLine(32)` or `Console.WriteLine(0x20)`. The same applies for plenty of other such constants.

Answer (score 3):

(Tested) - They do in fact result in the same computed value after compilation, the C# spec confirms:

> 10.4 Constants
>
> A constant is a class member that represents a constant
> value: a value that **can be
> computed** at compile-time. A
> constant-declaration introduces one or
> more constants of a given type.

Comment: That doesn't say that it necessarily gets compiled that way. If you wrote a C# compiler that did the calculation at runtime you'd still be in the letter of that spec.